# ansible: escaping \" string

Tags: escaping, ansible

I'm trying to add a line to file using `lineinfile` that contains the string `\"`.

let's say: `hello \" world \"`

The problem is that string is the way to escape only the `"` character.

any ideas?

EDIT:
I tried `\\\"` and `\\\\"` with no luck

Comment: escape both characters: \\\"

Comment: @kgh I tried this one, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting your whole `line` in **single quotes** will do the trick.

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: ensure escaped hello world
      lineinfile:
        dest=/home/vagrant/hello_world
        line='Hello \" world\"'
```

Result:

```
$ cat /home/vagrant/hello_world 
Hello \" world\"
```

Comment: Weird. I am getting `hello " world "`. I thought it might be related to my ansible version (1.7.1) but it happens on 1.8.2 as well (upgraded and checked)

Comment: Well the single quote did do the trick. However, for me the right syntax was `'hello \\" world  \\"'`